# Read Extremely large file efficiently in C#. Currently using StreamReader

Tags: c#

I have a Json file that is sized 50GB and beyond.
Following is what I have written to read a very small chunk of the Json. I now need to modify this to read the large file.

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> ReadJson<T>(string filePath)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        String line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
        // the file is reached.
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
            XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(jsonBytes, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
            var myPerson = ser.ReadObject(jsonReader);
            jsonReader.Close();

            yield return (T)myPerson;
        }
    }
}
```

1. Would it suffice if I specify the buffer size while constructing the StreamReader in the current code?
2. Please correct me if I am wrong here.. The buffer size basically specifies how much data is read from disk to memory at a time. So if File is 100MB in size with buffer size as 5MB, it reads 5MB at a time to memory, until entire file is read.
3. Assuming my understanding of point 3 is right, what would be the ideal buffer size with such a large text file? Would int.Max size be a bad idea? In 64-bit PC int.Max size is 2147483647. I presume buffer size is in bytes, which evaluates to about 2GB. This itself could consume time. I was looking at something like 100MB - 300MB as buffer size.

Comment: Increasing the buffer size beyond even as low as 128K is unlikely to have much benefit. A 1MB buffer is already larger than it needs to be. The only way to be sure, however, is to time it with different buffer sizes.

Comment: 50gb file? if it's a credit card list can i have a copy please.(jk)

Answer (score 5):

It is going to read a line at a time (of the input file), which could be 10 bytes, and could be all 50GB. So it comes down to : how is the input file structured? And if the input JSON has newlines *other* than cleanly at the breaks between objects, this could get really ill.

The buffer size might impact how much it reads **while looking** for the end of each line, but ultimately: it needs to find a new-line each time (at least, how it is written currently).

Comment: The file structure is as follows

{<Data1>}
{<Data2>}
{<Data3>}

Basically each data entry with braces - {} and then an enter key after that.

As I understand from what you have written, this is not very efficient since It reads from file each data entry. I would like it to read parts of file to memory and then from there read each line. How do i modify this?

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs well, how long is each line? (I assume each `<Data1>` etc is a line). I honestly don't think this is a problem. It sounds to me like you're chasing a performance issue that isn't actually there, or isn't what you think it is

Comment: Each line is around 1KB. 
Yes, Thats right. I am presuming that my code is not going to be very efficient. I thought it is more efficient to read chunks of file into memory and then reading it.

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs when it comes to performance, "presuming" is an error

Comment: :) Yes we will be measuring the performance in sometime. 
I felt I should modify this before we get started. So as I understand from your comments, this is a pretty efficient way in itself.

Comment: Yes, there will already be some buffering etc; you could always add a BufferedStream if you are concerned

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I just found an [msdn link (Filestream and BufferedStream - Brad Abrams)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/15/114329.aspx?Redirected=true) which talks about the same context. Here is an extract.
"I don’t think there are any Streams in the .NET Framework that require it"

Comment: My current algorithm is basically, 1. Read data entry from disk file. 2. Write data entry to database. 3. Store 'data entry index' in a hash table.

While the current implementation seems decent on paper. Can I not better this considering a High end PC with multiple processors? If the file is like 50GB in size, using each processor/threads to work in a parallel fashion, with each thread working on a small chunk of maybe 25MB. So if there are 2 threads, thread (a) reads 25MB, thread (b) reads next 25MB. Meanwhile thread (a) processes data, thread (b) processes data, and back to reading.

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs if you are interested in performance, frankly a better question would be: why are you using JSON?

Comment: Current Data is in Json format. This needs to be transferred to a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first compare different parsers before worrying about details as the buffer size.
The differences between DataContractJsonSerializer, [Raven JSON](https://github.com/ravendb/Raven.Json) or [Newtonsoft JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) will be quite significant.

Answer (score 0):

So your main issue with this is where are your boundaries, and given that your doc is a JSON doc it seems to me likely that your boundaries are likely to be classes, I assume (or hope) that you don't have 1 honking great class that is 50gb large. I also assume that you don't really need all those classes in memory but you may need to search the whole thing for your subset...does that sound roughly right? if so I think that your pseudo code is something like

```
using a Json parser that accepts a streamreader (newtonsoft?)
read and parse until eof
  yield return your parsed class that matches criteria
  read and parse next class
end
```

Comment: My algorithm is basically, 
1. Read data entry from disk file.
2. Write data entry to database.
3. Store 'data entry index' in a hash table.

Comment: @ShaQ.Blogs cool, very similar to the above then. So I think this is what you need then, simply use a JSON parser that will parse from a stream and write to the db as you go. NewtonSoft.Json or Raven.Json are your best bets.