# How to avoid "Out Of Memory" exception when reading large files using File.ReadAllText(x)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

This is my code to search for a string for all files and folders in the drive "G:\" that contains the string "hello":

```
Dim path = "g:\"
Dim fileList As New List(Of String)

 GetAllAccessibleFiles(path, fileList)

 'Convert List<T> to string array if you want
  Dim files As String() = fileList.ToArray

  For Each s As String In fileList
      Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText(s)
      Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("hello")
      If index >= 0 Then
           MsgBox("FOUND!")
           ' String is in file, starting at character "index"
      End If
  Next
```

This code will also results in memory leak/out of memory exception (as I read file as big as 5GB!). Perhaps it will bring the whole file to the RAM, then went for the string check.

```
Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Farizluqman\mybigmovie.mp4") 
    ' this file sized as big as 5GB!
    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("hello")
    If index >= 0 Then
        MsgBox("FOUND!")
        ' String is in file, starting at character "index"
    End If
```

But, the problem is: This code is really *DANGEROUS*, that may lead to memory leak or using 100% of the RAM. The question is, is there any way or workaround for the code above? Maybe chunking or reading part of the file and then dispose to avoid memory leak/out of memory? Or is there any way to minimize the memory usage when using the code? As I felt responsible for other's computer stability. Please Help :)

Comment: StreamReader has an Exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 for OutOfMemory

Comment: reading a binary file (.MP4) using a text file reader seems ill advised

Comment: I was hunting for codes and testing it. perhaps the user can have a text file, but with an extension of .MP4? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `System.IO.StreamReader`, which reads line by line instead all the lines at the same time (here you have a similar [post in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068934/read-extremely-large-file-efficiently-in-c-currently-using-streamreader)); I personally never use ReadAll*** unless under very specific conditions. Sample adaptation of your code:

```
Dim index As Integer = -1
Dim lineCount As Integer = -1
Using reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Farizluqman\mybigmovie.mp4")
    Dim line As String
    line = reader.ReadLine
    If (line IsNot Nothing AndAlso line.Contains("hello")) Then
        index = line.IndexOf("hello")
    Else
        If (line IsNot Nothing) Then lineCount = line.Length
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            line = reader.ReadLine
            If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
                lineCount = lineCount + line.Length
                If (line.Contains("hello")) Then
                    index = lineCount - line.Length + line.IndexOf("hello")
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Using

If index >= 0 Then
    MsgBox("FOUND!")
    ' String is in file, starting at character "index"
End If
```

Comment: the given codes = MAGIC! works like a charm, although I don't quite understand about it. did streamreader have built-in OutOfMemory exception? anyhow, the code didn't use up the memory and work like intended :)

Comment: @FarizLuqman No magic really :) The difference between this approach and yours is that out of the millions of lines in your file; this code reads just one at a time. Your code reads all the lines at the same time and, apparently, are too many for the memory of the given computer. That's why it is not too recommendable to use ReadAllLines or similar (ReallAllText, etc.), because stores the whole file in the memory and some files are too big; better doing things step by step :)

Comment: I see :) so when the program finished searching in the current line, it will just dispose and went to the next one? lol, any solutions is like magic to me

Comment: One note of caution.  This assumes that the file has 'lines', which it apparently does.

Comment: @dbasnett did you mean null line? I have corrected this right now.

Comment: @FarizLuqman The using statement will take care of all the closing/disposing related actions, yes.

Comment: I meant that the code assumes that there ARE Newlines as part of the data.  Apparently the file you are working with does have Newlines.

Comment: @dbasnett In the most likely scenario, the information contained in files is divided into lines (not sure what is the limitation if any for the line length of files under Windows). Otherwise, the OP would have to use non-standard approaches, as far as the standard approach is using StreamReader with lines. A priori, I would say that this approach (relying on StreamReader+lines) should avoid any memory related issue in 99% of the cases. It is difficult to imagine a single line with a size of various GBs (if possible at all)!

Comment: @varocarbas - In this case it appears that the assumption is correct.

Comment: @dbasnett The OP was happy with the result. In any case, as said, I didn't propose this solution just for the OP (and by hoping that his file would meet the expected conditions), but as the standard proceeding for these situations. I haven't ever seen a (GBs-big) file having just 1 line; not completely sure if this is impossible but, at least, extremely unlikely. And not only for text files, but also any other encrypted file (e.g., pdf, Word docs, audio/video files, etc.). But if you find any solid reference representing an exception to this assumption, I would be happy to add it to my answer.

Comment: @varocarbas - I can think of one text file format that typically doesn't use newlines, javascript, though I have never seen one very large.  Here is one, http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js .  For newline based files your solution works.

Comment: @dbasnett I created a new text file, copied all the contents from your link without doing anything else and, as a result, I got 86 lines. But I know what you mean with JavaScript code compression; although cannot imagine a JavaScript code over 1GB and, even in this case, it seems that when you copy the code into a file in Windows new lines are being added automatically.